# How should I get Xcode to link an iOS project that uses a C++ static library

Tags: xcode

Using Xcode, I've written a Cocoa Touch static library, mainly in C++. It exposes a C interface for the benefit of Objective-C client code.

I have a client iOS app that uses it, and everything works and runs as expected, except that I found I needed to include a minimal `.cpp` file in the client project to get the link to succeed. Otherwise I get C++-related unresolved symbols, e.g. `operator new(unsigned long)`.

The above hack is easy and effective, and so I guess I'm not breaking any laws, but is there a proper way to eliminate my linker errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be just a matter of adding `-lc++` to the linker flags in the project settings, I'd have thought.

Add it under "Other Linker Flags" under "Linking" section of the "Build Settings" tab on your project's settings.

Comment: The required linker term seems to be -stdlib=libc++, which I can force with even an empty C++ file in the project, but otherwise I can't see how to get it set. I've only been using Xcode for a few months so it's quite possible I haven't found the right place.. "Other C flags" seem to make no difference to the link options (dumped in the error log), and Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries gives me too many C++ libraries to choose from, none of which may be right.

Comment: I can add -lstdc++ as an Other Linker Option as suggested, though I in fact need -lc++ instead, to pick up the C++11 stuff that I'm using. The danger is that this may clash with the explicit 'C++ Standard Library' option, that gets ignored in the absence of a .cpp file, though it really shouldn't. So I think my hack is actually safer, in that the lib picked up will be the one corresponding to the latter option, with no danger of clash.

Comment: The current default value for the C++ Standard Library option, by the way, produces - when it is not ignored - `-stdlib=libc++` which corresponds to `-lc++` not `-lstdc++`.