# Xcode: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, debugging

When a crash occur (using a test device connected to Xcode, in my case iPhone 4s with iOS 9), Xcode 7 fails to load debug data for some of the system classes, hence it displays the aforementioned error. I'm working with a Swift 2.1 project. Does any one know how to fix it and make it load such data? It has proven to be hellish trying to debug when this happen.

PS: It has nothing to do with the type of crash, it is just an Xcode problem.

Comment: You need an *All Exceptions breakpoint*

Comment: have you played around with with 'Linking' under 'Build Settings' for your project? Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129990/how-should-i-get-xcode-to-link-an-ios-project-that-uses-a-c-static-library maybe try adding `-ObjC` to your `Other Linker Flags` or make sure that 'Link with Standard Libraries` is yes, or make sure `Enable Modules (C and ObjC)` is yes, or `Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support` is yes.. etc.

Comment: @Louis All of them are set just as you said :(

Comment: @Wongzigii Adding that breakpoint did not help