# Can't read XML file in my Swift program. NSBundle failure

Tags: xml, xcode, swift, xcode7.3

I can't seem to get my code to work. I have included a "sample.xml" file in my Xcode project folder. However, I keep getting an error saying:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available."

I'm also using a third party library to parse my XML file.

**What I have already tried**: checking the target, included the file in project. The error shows up on the first line saying "found nil while unwrapping optional"

```
let xmlPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "xml")!

let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlPath)

if let parser = XMLParser(data: data) {
    let element = parser.rootElement["root"]
    print(element)

}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with linker flags? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130042/5654848).

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you added the delegate `NSXMLParserDelegate` to your class?